# How to play ffmpeg dash?

Tags: django, ffmpeg, mpeg-dash

I have following code to create chunk of video.

```
permission_classes=[AllowAny]
video_serializer = serializers.video_serializer

def process_video(self, video_path, video_id):
    # Set the path where the processed videos will be saved
    output_dir = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'processed_videos')

     # Create the output directory if it doesn't exist
    os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)

    # Add your ffmpeg_streaming code here to process the video
    full_video_path =  os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, str(video_path))
    print(video_path)
    video = ffmpeg_streaming.input(full_video_path)
    print(video)

      # Add your ffmpeg_streaming code here to process the video
    _144p  = Representation(Size(256, 144), Bitrate(95 * 1024, 64 * 1024))
    _240p  = Representation(Size(426, 240), Bitrate(150 * 1024, 94 * 1024))
    _360p  = Representation(Size(640, 360), Bitrate(276 * 1024, 128 * 1024))
    _480p  = Representation(Size(854, 480), Bitrate(750 * 1024, 192 * 1024))
    _720p  = Representation(Size(1280, 720), Bitrate(2048 * 1024, 320 * 1024))

    dash = video.dash(Formats.h264())
    dash.representations(_144p, _240p, _360p, _480p, _720p)
    dash.output(os.path.join(output_dir, f'dash-stream-{video_id}.mpd'))


def post(self,request):
    try:
        video_data = self.video_serializer(data=request.data)
        video_data.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        data = video_data.validated_data

        video_instance = Video.objects.create(
            id = data.get('id'),
            saved_location = data.get('video')
        )
        video_instance.save()

        self.process_video(video_instance.saved_location, video_instance.id)
        return Response({"success":True})
    except Exception as e:
        return Response({"success":False,"message":str(e)})
```

This code is working well as it has created different chunk files as well as a `.mpd` file of a video inside `media/processed_video` folder.

Then I wrote following code to stream that video using that `.mpd` folder.

```
    def get (self,request,video_id):
    try:
        mpd_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'processed_videos', f'dash-stream-{video_id}.mpd')
        
        with open(mpd_path, 'rb') as f:
            mpd_content = f.read()
            response = HttpResponse(mpd_content, content_type='application/dash+xml')

            # Set Content-Disposition header to make the response downloadable
            response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename="dash-stream-{video_id}.mpd"'
            
            # Optionally set Content-Length header to specify the size of the file
            response['Content-Length'] = len(mpd_content)
            
            return response
        
    except Exception as e:
        return Response({"success":False,"message":str(e)})
```

When I make get request to the api it returns content of `.mpd` as it is (i.e xml). When I used that api in `vlc network stream`, vlc couldn't play the video. But when I dragged `.mpd` file directly to vlc, the video gets played with 144p only. I don't know where I got wrong in `GET`. Please help.